# How to create this type of background-image with text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image, text-align

So, from some time I'm trying to do this with Bootstrap, but I can't find a working way.Maybe it's something even more simple than the things i'm trying, i don't know anymore.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7HVl.jpg
Please for some suggestions.Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score -2):

Here are the basics of absolute positioning inside relative containers:

Relative positioned containers are **relative** to other elements on the page. 
A relative containers margin will always go from the last element on your page, not your page as a whole.

See https://jsfiddle.net/kknfLfh5/ for an example of relative positioned elements.

div2 has a

```
top: 0;
```

property, but it's not on the upper page border rather than at the lower border of div1.

If we changed the positioning of div2 to absolute, it will look like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gh3bku88/).

We now have an absolute positioned div that ignores it's siblings and positiones itself on page level.

With your image, you want a similiar approach. Try wrapping your image inside a wrapper div that has relative positioning. Your text should have absolute positioning like this:

Css:

```
.wrapper{
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

img{
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

h1{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

p{
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 10px;
}
```

and your html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
    <h1>
        I am a header.
    </h1>
    <p>
        I am text.
    </p>
</div>
```

Check this fiddle for a working sample: https://jsfiddle.net/4osq7tqo/